# Entity Framework - Exclusão de objeto com relacionamento

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

Estou com uma dúvida para entender o comportamento do Entity. Pois quando eu passo `null` para uma propriedado o Entity não deveria fazer "limpar" o relacionamento no banco?

Minha Model:

```
public partial class Ocorrencia
{
    [Key]
    public int id { get; set; }
    public Pessoa Pessoa { get; set; }
    public int? PessoaId { get; set; }
}

public class Pessoa
    {
        [Key]
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string nome { get; set; }
    }
```

Meu Context:

```
public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<MoradaWeb.Models.Ocorrencia> Ocorrencia { get; set; }
```

Acontece que quando eu chamo o comando:

```
var Ocorrencia = db.Ocorrencia.FirstOrDefault(c => c.id == id);
Ocorrencia.Pessoa = null;
```

A propriedade PessoaId não está sendo "zerada".

> O Entity não deveria zerar a propriedade PessoaID automaticamente?

OBS: A busca pelo objeto já está sendo feito corretamente (com o objeto Pessoa preenchido de acordo com o id em PessoaId)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você não carregou `Pessoa`. Precisa carregar o objeto para o contexto observá-lo:

```
var Ocorrencia = db.Ocorrencia
                   .Include(o => o.Pessoa)
                   .FirstOrDefault(c => c.id == id);

Ocorrencia.Pessoa = null;
db.SaveChanges();
```